# osmconvert border problem

Tags: openstreetmap, osmconvert

I tried to add a border to my osm file to make is smaller.

The command line is as follows:

```
osmconvert china.osm -b=22.30,114.11,22.38,114.22 --out-osm -o=hk.osm
```

an error occurred like this:

```
osmconvert Error: use border format:  -b="x1,y1,x2,y2"
```

I then tried following the border format by adding the two colons but still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have swapped X and Y.

Try with

```
osmconvert china.osm -b=114.11,22.30,114.22,22.38 --out-osm -o=hk.osm
```